# GraphQL Apollo Android не создает класс

Tags: android, android-studio, компиляция, graphql

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема!

Подключил Apollo for Android (добавил основные зависимости):

```
 classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:gradle-plugin:0.3.2'
 implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:0.5.0'
 implementation "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-android-support:0.5.0"
```

Положил схему и описание query в отдельную папку: **src/mail/graphql/myapplication3/...**

Нажимаю **Rebuild** и вылетают ошибки:

```
error: cannot find symbol class Field
error: MyApplication3.EventsConnection.Data is not abstract and does not override abstract method marshaller() in com.apollographql.apollo.api.Operation.Data
error: map(ResponseReader) in Mapper cannot implement map(ResponseReader) in ResponseFieldMapper
overridden method does not throw IOException
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in interface ResponseFieldMapper
```

Сам файл класса создается, но в нем ошибка импорта библиотеки: **import com.apollographql.apollo.api.Field**

Чего не хватает?

Comment: судя по всему не хватает какой то либы.